# How can I find a twitter user using his profile picture?

Tags: twitter

I have a profile picture and I would like to know how I can find the user only using the profile picture.
I also know one person that that user if following but there are 24k thousand others following that person.

I was wondering whether there is a command that can cycle through all those 24,000 followers and reverse image search for my profile picture.

Answer (score 0):

On the image part, there isn't support in the Twitter API for that. However, here's how you can approach the problem. Assuming you have the ID of the user whose followers you're scanning, use the [Followers](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/users/follows/api-reference/get-users-id-followers) endpoint. Make sure you've specified the `profile_image_url` in the `user.fields` parameter. You can use that to download the URL with the user's profile image.

After that, you have to build your own image recognition model that takes two images and produces a probability of how similar they are. You have to take care of this part yourself.